# JQGRID How to change row number (rownum) text color on selected highlighted rows?

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid looking like this :

[image]

I would like to change the rownum text color on the selected rows so it can be white like the rest of the text when highlighted.

I managed to change the default color by doing this in CSS :

```
.jqgrow .jqgrid-rownum  { background-color: transparent; background-image: none; color:#ffffff}
```

But i don't know how to do the same for the highlight state.

I tried with `.ui-state-highlight` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
.ui-state-highlight > .jqgrid-rownum{color: red !important}
```

Edit: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3rL7vgoc/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the ">" a typo ? or is it necessary ? I've tried without and it still working great ...

Comment: ">" is the selector for children elements, but don't use it if it's not necesary